Does it make sense to say a quintic equation has a "repeated quadratic root"?
Regarding the following question from a Further Maths textbook:

The equation $2x^5+x^4+36x^3+18x^2+162x+81=0$ has a repeated
quadratic root.
a) Show that $x=3i$ is a solution of the equation
b) Fully factorise the equation

Part a) prompts us that $x-3i$ is a factor from which we can deduce $x+3i$ is also a factor and further that $x^2+9$ is a factor. What confuses me is the 'repeated quadratic root' - I don't believe I have heard this term before and I assumed it meant that of the three remaining linear factors, one would be repeated - ie. there was some solution $a$ such that $(x-a)^2$ is a factor.
This however proved to be incorrect and it turns out that the factorised equation is simply $(x^2+9)^2(2x+1)=0$
My impression is that it seems strange to refer to this as a 'repeated quadratic root', but perhaps 'repeated quadratic factor' would make sense instead. Can anyone share any insight on the convention for such factorisations?

I would have expected "quadratic" in this context to mean a root that is an algebraic number of degree $2$, so a "repeated quadratic root" would mean a root that is both repeated and quadratic. But your factorization shows there is no such root, so I am at a loss.

I think by quadratic root it means both values of $x$ that originate from a typical quadratic equation,i.e. $$x=\frac{-b±\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ By "repeated quadratic roots, it indicates the presence of two such "double" roots which are equal to each other.

The terminology is sloppy. It should be said the polynomial has a repeated quadratic factor, not the equation has a repeated quadratic root. Also, an equation doesn't have a factorization, the polynomial has a factorization. I can certainly imagine writing it this way for beginners, but it seems imprecise, unless it was translated from another language with different implicit meanings.

Side note, we can check for a repeated factor   by finding the GCD   of the original polynomial $f(x)$   and its  (formal)  derivative  $f'(x).$  In this case all coefficients for $f'$   were even,  so were halved. The process is algorithmic; still, this time the coefficients are comically large.
$$ f(x)= \left(  2 x^{5}  +  x^{4}  + 36 x^{3}  + 18 x^{2}  + 162 x  + 81 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{1}{2} f'(x) = \left(  5 x^{4}  + 2 x^{3}  + 54 x^{2}  + 18 x  + 81 \right)  $$
$$  \left(  2 x^{5}  +  x^{4}  + 36 x^{3}  + 18 x^{2}  + 162 x  + 81 \right)  =  \left(  5 x^{4}  + 2 x^{3}  + 54 x^{2}  + 18 x  + 81 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 10 x  + 1 }{ 25 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 358 x^{3}  + 216 x^{2}  + 3222 x  + 1944 }{ 25 }  \right)  $$
$$  \left(  5 x^{4}  + 2 x^{3}  + 54 x^{2}  + 18 x  + 81 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 358 x^{3}  + 216 x^{2}  + 3222 x  + 1944 }{ 25 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 22375 x  - 4550 }{ 64082 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 308025 x^{2}  + 2772225 }{ 32041 }  \right)  $$
$$  \left(   \frac{ 358 x^{3}  + 216 x^{2}  + 3222 x  + 1944 }{ 25 }  \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 308025 x^{2}  + 2772225 }{ 32041 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 11470678 x  + 6920856 }{ 7700625 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 10 x  + 1 }{ 25 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 10 x  + 1 }{ 25 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 22375 x  - 4550 }{ 64082 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 8950 x^{2}  - 925 x  + 63900 }{ 64082 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 22375 x  - 4550 }{ 64082 }  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 11470678 x  + 6920856 }{ 7700625 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 64082 x^{3}  + 32041 x^{2}  + 576738 x  + 288369 }{ 308025 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 160205 x^{2}  + 64082 x  + 288369 }{ 308025 }  \right) } $$
$$  \left(  2 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  + 18 x  + 9 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 895 x  - 182 }{ 24642 }  \right)  -  \left(  5 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 9 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 358 x^{2}  - 37 x  + 2556 }{ 24642 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$
$$  \mbox{confirming  GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 9 \right) }   $$
$$  \left(  2 x^{5}  +  x^{4}  + 36 x^{3}  + 18 x^{2}  + 162 x  + 81 \right)  =  \left(  2 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  + 18 x  + 9 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 9 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(  5 x^{4}  + 2 x^{3}  + 54 x^{2}  + 18 x  + 81 \right)  =  \left(  5 x^{2}  + 2 x  + 9 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 9 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(  2 x^{5}  +  x^{4}  + 36 x^{3}  + 18 x^{2}  + 162 x  + 81 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 895 x  - 182 }{ 24642 }  \right)  -  \left(  5 x^{4}  + 2 x^{3}  + 54 x^{2}  + 18 x  + 81 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 358 x^{2}  - 37 x  + 2556 }{ 24642 }  \right)  =  \color{blue}{  \left(   -  x^{2}  - 9 \right)  } $$
$$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 9 \right) }   $$
